# Clean way to have project-varying sys.path in Spyder

Tags: python, pythonpath, spyder

I often have a collection of .py files, maybe split over a few folders, that all use some little special purpose library I've written that doesn't belong in my general PYTHONPATH. What's the cleanest way for me to get that library into the Python path for those scripts that need it? I'll be the only one ever to run any of these, and I will generally be doing so from Spyder.

I've tried with .pth files. This may not be the best way, but I can't get them to work regardless. For example, if I create a .pth file containing

```
/var
```

The running the following code out of the same directory via Spyder, I get output of True, False, True:

```
import sys
import site

print any(["python" in path for path in sys.path]) # True
print any(["/var" in path for path in sys.path]) # False
site.addsitedir(".")
print any(["/var" in path for path in sys.path]) # True
```

Here are the details of my environment:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.7.1, SciPy 0.13.0, Matplotlib 1.3.1
```

Comment: I think I'd just recommend you add them to your PYTHONPATH ... Are you worried about namespace clashes or something?

Comment: @mgilson, I suppose on some level I am worried about namespace clahses; also it keeps everything better organized so I can tell what code is using what other code. But to be honest I hadn't considered your solution, simple as it is.

Comment: It would avoid you needing to add a bunch of annoying boilerplate code to all of your projects.  As long as the modules are named reasonably, I don't really see any major downsides ...